# lot of bitcoinj clients have connected to me

Tags: bitcoind

Looking at my peers list in the debug window for my node, I can see that a lot of bitcoinj clients have connected to me. Is this any cause for concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If their IP addresses are all 52.*, then they're lying about being BitcoinJ and are really attacking you / the network. If so, ban them. If their IPs are all different, it's fine.

Comment: lots if them starting with 52, how can i ban them ?

Comment: 52.* is a very large address space. Can you provide a source on why you believe they are all attackers?